# How to pass onFetch data from one data set to another in data design?

Tags: birt

I have two datasets in my data design and I want to pass the complete results of one data set to the other and accordingly I am modifying my query. But I see one issue that as soon as the first `onFetch()` occurs the flow is going to the other data set and post that the `onFetch()` continues.

The report design is like

1. First DataSet
2. Second DataSet

I am trying to pass the results of one data set to another so that I can use it in the where clause. The problem is that I cannot access both the data sets using a single connection profile.

the layout is like this

**Data Design**

1. DS1
2. DS2

**Report Design**

Data Source(Data design)

Data Sets(DS1, DS2)

Report flow
DS1 -> DS2

Is there any work around for this as I want to keep the data sets in the data design itself and not anywhere else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your question. How is your layout? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @hvb please check the edit it it helps.

Comment: Does your DS1 return more than one row and you need all the rows of DS1 in DS2 (I can hardly imagine that) ? Or do you just need to execute DS2 for each row of DS1?

Comment: the DS1 returns more than one row and i intend to make a list of all rows returned and pass it to DS2 beforeOpen()

Comment: And what do you want to do with the DS1 results in DS2? Use them in an IN clause?

Comment: yes. I want to use it in an IN clause.